# get Facebook Group Id using identifier or url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I would like to get a facebook group id by using a URL or specific identifier.

For ex: **http://www.facebook.com/groups/chennaifoodies/** should give group id 194462073956868.
Is there way to get the group id by using above URL or identifiers like 'chennaifoodies'?

If I tried **https://graph.facebook.com/chennaifoodies**, then it gives the fan page id.

I think 'wallflux' has done a wonderful script, so I need a script like that to get group the id.

is there any way to get a group id using graph api or fql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you can get the **Group ID** from the url you mentioned with the group username.

But, you surely can get the same with the url:

> http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=chennaifoodies&type=group&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Yes, you'll be needing an active user access token to query this.

Or, the graph API (the same thing)-

```
/search?q=chennaifoodies
```

[Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dchennaifoodies%26type%3Dgroup)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but im getting more results when i use the group identifier **namma.chennai**, group url: **'http://www.facebook.com/groups/namma.chennai/'**. if we unable to get group id, then how wallflux has done such a script. **http://www.wallflux.com/facebook_id/**